# Vuetify webpack alias css

Tags: css, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm using the vuetify webpack boilerplate (https://github.com/vuetifyjs/webpack) and I can't get the aliases in `/build/webpack.base.conf.js` to work for importing css (like `import "~assets/css/mycss.css"`) even though it's working like a charm for js import (like `import MyComponent from "components/MyComponent"`).

I tried several potential solutions I found, none seem to work...

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove .css at the end.

Change

```
import "~assets/css/mycss.css"
```

to

```
import "~assets/css/mycss"
```

For more details, check this: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#imports